# Eliminar documento de firebase con Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firestore, delete

Estoy eliminando un documento de mi coleccion en firebase pero solo se elimina si recargo la pagina, como puedo evitar esto y que se elimine al dar click en el boton y no al recargar
Esta es mi funcion que elimina:

```
const deleteReport = async (id) => {
    const colRef = collection(db, "tables");
    await deleteDoc(doc(colRef, id));
  };
```

y aqui la ejecuto

```
 <Icon icon="ant-design:delete-outlined" onClick={() => {deleteReport(el.id)}} />
```

Comment: Quieres decir que se elimina automáticamente al recargar la página o al dar clic y luego recargar?

Comment: @Sr1871 actualmente se me elimina solo si recargo la pagina, pero no quiero eso. Sino que cuando de click sobre el boton se elimine de una vez.

Comment: Ahi efectivamente estás eliminando el elemento de la base de datos, pero no veo que estés actualizando la UI con los nuevos valores... tienes algun estado en donde almacenes esa "coleccion" de la que hablas? como estás "pintando" esa coleccion en la pantalla?

Comment: @Pipe Tienes razon no estaba actualizando el estado. Ya lo corregí, gracias!